# Does NSAutorelease need to be the first line in main?

Tags: objective-c

Just curious does NSAutoreleasePool need to be right at the top of main, or can you declare variables before it?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int myNumber;
    int myOtherNumber;

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

cheers -gary-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are not allocating any Objective-C objects (and autoreleasing them) you should be fine.
I don't know why you want to do this?

Comment: I was just curious, I will declare things underneath, seems better practice ... thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create the pool at anytime, you just don't want to declare Autorelease variables before you declare the pool.

Comment: That should be "you don't want to autorelease objects" — there's no such thing as an autorelease variable and obviously no way of creating one.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Don't do the autoreleasy thing with no pool.

Comment: @jeff +1 for legitimate use of "autoreleasy" =D